# Nginx and PHP-FPM on two separated server

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have two separeted server. The first is an nginx server with 192.168.122.2 ip addr. The second is a PHP-fpm server with 192.168.122.3 ip address. I have to modify my nginx to use the other php-fpm server.

My nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 192.168.122.3:9000;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;


                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
```

In the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf I added the listening ip:

```
listen = 192.168.122.3:9000
```

But I got 502 Bad gateway error.

And I got these errors on nginx:

```
2016/01/24 03:11:05 [error] 3902#0: *4 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.122.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.122.3:9000", host: "192.168.1.179:8084"
2016/01/24 03:11:05 [alert] 3902#0: *4 write() to "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (28: No space left on device) while logging request, client: 192.168.122.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.122.3:9000", host: "192.168.1.179:8084"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, but based on the second log line you lack disk space, and that causes all kinds of errors, including connections to backend servers.

Comment: These are linux containers so I have no idea how can I add some more space.